# How to set default headers on outgoing requests, when the interceptor runs before a value is emitted from a service

Tags: angular, jwt, angular-http-interceptors

I have issue passing a token from POST response in `auth.service.ts` into a HttpInterceptor and set the token in the authorization header.
As I understand an interceptor runs before any HTTP requests, intercepts, modify and return a cloned version.

But my header isn't getting updated. The interceptor just returns the default value of `tokenSubject$` which is `null`, before the auth.service have run and the new value of the BehaviorSubject has been emitted.

**brower console**

```
interceptor null
auth.service.ts:19 {token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9..."}
auth.service.ts:21 eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9...
```

**Raw headers**

```
Host: localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:4200/login
Authorization: Bearer null
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 52
Origin: http://localhost:4200
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
```

How am I supposed to add a token to an Authorization header?

---

**auth.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  tokenSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  login(userEmailAndPassword: { email: string, password: string }) {
    return this.httpClient
      .post<{ token: string }>('http://localhost:3000/users/login', userEmailAndPassword)
      .subscribe(user => {
        console.log(user); // { token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI..." }
        this.tokenSubject$.next(user.token);
        console.log(this.tokenSubject$.value); // "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI..."
      });
  }
}
```

**jwt-interceptor.ts**

```js
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const setAuthorizationToken = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.authService.tokenSubject$.value}`)
    });
    console.log('interceptor', this.authService.tokenSubject$.value);
    return next.handle(setAuthorizationToken);
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { JwtInterceptor } from './jwt-interceptor';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { UsersComponent } from './users/users.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent},
  {path: 'users', component: UsersComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    UsersComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [{provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

---

**HTTP Request**

```
POST http://localhost:3000/users/login
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "email": "mr@mr.com",
  "password": "myawesomepassword"
}
```

**HTTP Response**

```
POST http://localhost:3000/users/login

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 209
ETag: W/"d1-MJNo/MXLpxhkX1PE78vlqkKR5GQ"
Date: Wed, 28 Aug 2019 09:07:42 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

{
  "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9..."
}

Response code: 200 (OK); Time: 15ms; Content length: 209 bytes
```

Comment: this should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55711337/angular-http-interceptor-subscribing-to-observable-and-then-returning-next-handl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save the auth token somewhere else than the service, as it is going to be null, everytime the page gets reloaded. I suggest to use localstorage:

```
login(userEmailAndPassword: { email: string, password: string }) {
    return this.httpClient
      .post<{ token: string }>('http://localhost:3000/users/login', userEmailAndPassword)
      .subscribe(user => {
        console.log(user); // { token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI..." }
        this.tokenSubject$.next(user.token);

        localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);// --> Here u are saving the token to localstorage

        console.log(this.tokenSubject$.value); // "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI..."
      });
  }
```

also u could save the whole user object:

```
login(userEmailAndPassword: { email: string, password: string }) {
        return this.httpClient
          .post<{ token: string }>('http://localhost:3000/users/login', userEmailAndPassword)
          .subscribe(user => {
            console.log(user); // { token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI..." }
            this.tokenSubject$.next(user.token);

            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));// --> Here u are saving the user to localstorage

            console.log(this.tokenSubject$.value); // "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI..."
          });
      }
```

to retrieve the user from localstorage u would have to parse it as JSON:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
```

then in ur interceptor do this:

```
        const setAuthorizationToken = request.clone({
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token') === null ? '' : localStorage.getItem('token');
            })
        });
```

Usually I write a UserService for retrieving the token/user from the localstorage.

Regards

Comment: I thought localStorage was a no-go and that storing in a header is preferable https://youtu.be/H0u4eiV9YiY?t=342 but what do I know. I can't even get it working :D

Comment: Localstorage in my opinion would be a nogo if u would store passwords in cleartext. But, frontend Apps are usually unsafe, as they are easy to attack.

Comment: did it work for u? if so then pls markk as solved, if not let me know!

Comment: Yes it did. It worked as you stated it would :D Thanks. But that Local Storage part still doesn't sit well with me. But I guess that is how it has to be.